# MySQL key value schema, returning results that must match multiple keys

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to utilise a simple key value innoDB table to construct a query that will return all applicable results

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_metadata` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_metadata_key_index` (`key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO
  `user_metadata` (
    `id`,
    `user_id`,
    `key`,
    `value`,
    `created_at`,
    `updated_at`
  )
VALUES
  (1, 1, 'nickname', 'bobby'),
  (2, 1, 'pet', 'dog'),
  (3, 1, 'transport', 'car'),
  (4, 2, 'nickname', 'andy'),
  (5, 2, 'pet', 'dog'),
  (6, 2, 'transport', 'car') (, 3, 'nickname', 'jonny'),
  (7, 3, 'nickname', 'jonno'),
  (8, 3, 'pet', 'cat'),
  (9, 3, 'transport', 'bike')
```

The data i have supplied is simplified, our real data uses 20-ish different unique keys per user_id

What i am trying to achieve is return all of the records where pet= dog AND transport=car by user_id, so both keys must have the given value on a per user basis.

In a traditional database schema this would be trivial, this schema design has advantages so i would prefer not to restructure the schema if possible, however i am unsure how to approach this, should i be looking at inner selects / inner joins etc?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For performance, add `INDEX(user_id, key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM user_metadata
INNER JOIN user_metadata AS subQ
USING(user_id)
WHERE user_metadata.key = 'pet'
AND user_metadata.value = 'dog'
AND subQ.key = 'transport'
AND subQ.value = 'car';`
```